# Capslock triggered hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

Here's my code:

```
state := GetKeyState("Capslock", "T")
if state = true
F1::Run explorer
F2::Run notepad
F3::Run Calc
F4::
if state = false
return
```

i want this part:

```
F1::Run explorer
F2::Run notepad
F3::Run Calc
F4::
```

only available when the capslock is on and disabled when the capslock is off. how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ahk_L you can use #IF.

You can toggle a variable on/off with Capslock and use that variable in the #IF to set the hotkeys, just like you would with the normal #IfWinActive. Or read the state of CapsLock immediately like this:

```
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1
F1::Run explorer
F2::Run notepad
F3::Run Calc
#If
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and i'm trying the solution now

Comment: The "#IF" worked! thanks. can you tell me how to start the explorer in "My Computer" and not in "Libraries" ?

Comment: I've found the solution. to start the explorer in "My Computer", use "shell:MyComputerFolder"